# WPF MenuItem Foreground is setting to child menus - only want it on main menu

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF menu which I set the foreground colour to a binding (using a converter), say the Foreground of my top level menu goes to Green for example, all the child menus under it go green (which I do not want).

Code sample:
I want the Finishing Position top menu to go green or whatever the converter tells it do.
However I do not want the sub MenuItemDeleteSelection to go to that same colour I want it just to be black or the default greyed out when it's command binding is Can Execute= false).

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding FinishingPosition,Converter={StaticResource FinishingPositionToDisplayTextConverter1}}"  Height="17" Width="12" Padding="0" Name="SelectionStatusHeader" Foreground="{Binding FinishingPosition,Converter={StaticResource FinishingPositionToColourConverter1}}" Background="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
        <MenuItem Name="MenuItemDeleteSelection" Header="Delete Selection"
                    Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteSelectionCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply have `default style for MenuItem` in your Menu resources so that it gets applied automatically to all your menu items.

Set default value to be **SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey** which will get applied to all menu items except for the one which overrides it.

```
<Menu>
   <Menu.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
           <Setter Property="Foreground"
              Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}}"/>
       </Style>
    </Menu.Resources>
    <MenuItem Foreground="Green"/>
    <MenuItem/>
    <MenuItem/>
</Menu>
```